# NGINX: different logs for two different websocket connections

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, tls1.2

We have two clients, one javascript and one C++. The C++ is using libwebsockets. Both of them try to connect via secure websockets (wss) to our websocket server via port 7000, that is sitting behind an NGINX server. When the javascript client connects, the connection is successful and in the NGINX 7000 port logs, this shows:

`[04/May/2018:12:25:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ Safari/537.36"`

However, when trying to connect with the C++ client, the connection fails and the logs show

`[04/May/2018:10:59:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 5 "-" "-"`

Why is it throwing a 400 instead of a 101 in the second case? We are not sure how to debug this. This is what we use in the websocket client

`ws->init("wss://echo.websocket.org:7000", nullptr, "your CA root file path");`

The client just says `Connection Failed`. We tried inspecting data with wireshark and enabling more logs in the NGINX server but we can't figure it out. What can it be about? Could it be because of miss-matched SSL/TLS versions?

Comment: Does your server require an `Origin` header? Does your C++ client sent one (normally it wouldn't, as this is a browser oriented header)? the log indicates a connection request failure, not a protocol or communication error. Test the HTTP headers on the C++ side against the server requirements to see what's wrong.

Comment: That's what we are trying (to compare headers) but we can't find them neither on the client or the NGINX server. We tried with wireshark on the client and logging on the NGINX server. We can't find packets with headers in wireshark, even though we do find the communication packets. We also can't find a way to see headers on NGINX

Comment: I'm old school that way, IMHO, the best way to test headers is to print them out to the console when before you send them on the network. TLS makes it hard to view headers... Also, if you don't get headers, your C++ client might be a TCP/IP socket client rather than a WebSocket client.

Comment: On your last note, could that be, even though we are using the constructor `ws->init`?

Comment: I honestly have no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the the client's library was not actually including the port number in the request, even when it's included in the connection URL. So either configuring NGINX to handle this specific case or making the library include the port in the request, solves the probem.